# What is the lexical scope of a function declared in another function's parameters

Tags: javascript

While coding, i faced a problem in resolving variables in a code similar to the code below:

```
 function foo(callback) {
     callback();
 }

foo( function(parameter) { 

    // how variables are resolved here? what is the outer scope?  

    console.log('helloWorld'); 
});
```

The questions are: 
 how variables are resolved inside the anonymous function defined in foo parameters spot? 
 I know that javascript resolve variables using the lexical scope, but in that function, what is the outer scope ?

Comment: The outer scope is the same block that the `foo( function(parameter) { ` call is on - anything defined in that block or an ancestor block will be visible inside the call to `foo`

Comment: "lexical" means the scope that the function is defined in, not the one that it is called from.

Comment: its all clear now, thank you so much for your help